# When would one use \XeTeXcharglyph rather than \iffontchar

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex

In XeLaTeX, both `\XeTeXcharglyph` and `\iffontchar` can be used to check whether a font contains a particular glyph.  In LuaLaTeX, `\iffontchar` seems to be the only option.  This is how both are used:

- `` \ifnum\XeTeXcharglyph`#1>0\found\else\notfound\fi ``
- `` \iffontchar\font`#1\found\else\notfound\fi ``

Is there any reason to prefer `\XeTeXcharglyph` over `\iffontchar`?

Comment: No and you're telling exactly why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the definition of the two commands in [`xetex.web`](https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/code/ci/master/tree/source/texk/web2c/xetexdir/xetex.web), you'll find that they are almost the same.

The main difference is that `\iffontchar` takes two arguments (font and glyph) and will always return a boolean, whereas `\XeTeXcharglyph` checks the glyph against the currently active font and might raise an error if the current font is not AAT, OTF, or Graphite.  This is actually a strong reason *against* using `\XeTeXcharglyph` because it cannot handle 8-bit fonts.

Internally both use `map_char_to_glyph`.

```lua
if_in_csname_code: b:=is_in_csname;
if_font_char_code:begin scan_font_ident; n:=cur_val; scan_usv_num;
  if is_native_font(n) then
    b:=(map_char_to_glyph(n, cur_val) > 0)
  else begin
    if (font_bc[n]<=cur_val)and(font_ec[n]>=cur_val) then
      b:=char_exists(char_info(n)(qi(cur_val)))
    else b:=false;
    end;
  end;
```

```lua
XeTeX_map_char_to_glyph_code:
  begin
    if is_native_font(cur_font) then begin
      scan_int; n:=cur_val; cur_val:=map_char_to_glyph(cur_font, n)
    end else begin
      not_native_font_error(last_item, m, cur_font); cur_val:=0
    end
  end;
```

MWE for failing `\XeTeXcharglyph` in Plain TeX:

```
\the\XeTeXcharglyph`a
\bye
```

```
! Cannot use \XeTeXcharglyph with cmr10; not a native platform font.
l.1 \the\XeTeXcharglyph
                       `a
```